# document.hasFocus() for chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Does anyone know what to use instead of hasFocus() for Chrome? I want to know when my Chrome tab has focus or not, so I can blink an alert message in the title.

Cheers

Comment: In the time since this question, Chrome has added support for document.hasFocus().

Comment: Though they have `document.hasFocus()` now, it actually returns `true` when it shouldn't. [Issue 64846](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64846)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen for the onfocus/onblur events and keep track of page state that way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
    <script>
      var has_focus = true;

      function print(str) {
        var out = document.getElementById('output')      
        out.innerText = out.innerText + "\n" + str;
      };

      window.onfocus = function() {
        print('focus');
        has_focus = true;
      };

      window.onblur = function() {
        print('blur');
        has_focus = false;
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: note that you'll be inferring that the page has focus when it's loaded, which might not always be the case.

Answer (score 3):

The page visibility API should do the trick:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

> **document.hidden**
>
> Returns true if the page is in a state considered to
> be hidden to the user, and false otherwise.

Of course, since this is a new API, you'll need to use different browser prefixes:

```
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
    hidden = "hidden";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "mozHidden";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
}
var isHidden = document[hidden];
// or even
var isFocused = !isHidden;
```

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me work around [this Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64846).

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `document.activeElement` tag.